# Excel macro Do While loop not compiling

Tags: excel, vba

Its a simple code to go to a sheet pull a row, go back to the first one sheet and paste it, then repeat until the value in column A of the inventory changes (New employee) at which point it needs to make a new worksheet to start storing the new data. And repeat until its done.

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

Set i = 2
Set j = 1
Do While i < 6
    Sheets("Inventory").Select
    If Cells("i,1").Value = Cells("i-1,1").Value Then
        Cells("i:i").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Sheetj").Select
        Cells("i,1").Select
        Selection.Paste
        i = i + 1
    Else
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        j = j + 1
        Sheets("Inventory").Select
        Cells("i:i").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Sheetj").Select
        Range("A3").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        i = i + 1
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you tried removing double quotes where ever `i` is meant to be the variable's value? Like `Cells("i:i")` .... changing it to `Cells(i & ":" & i)`

Comment: @PankajJaju, that's a very polite way of putting it. I'm sure that would help immensely :).

Comment: see my answer below. you don't need set to initialize integers. The code I pasted has no compilation errors. I dont have data to check that it does what you intended. I will leave that to you to figure out

Comment: @PankajJaju, `Cells("A1")` is not correct syntax, `Range("A1")` is correct one. The other options are: `Cells(i, 1)` or `Cells(i-1,1)`, etc.

Comment: Also massive ups to Seeking Alpha. Thanks a heap!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub test()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

i = 2 ' got rid of set
j = 1 ' got rid of set
Do While i < 6
    Sheets("Inventory").Select
    If Cells("i,1").Value = Cells("i-1,1").Value Then
        Cells("i:i").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Sheetj").Select
        Cells("i,1").Select
        Selection.Paste
        i = i + 1
    Else
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        j = j + 1
        Sheets("Inventory").Select
        Cells("i:i").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Sheets" & j).Select ' for completeness...
        Range("A3").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        i = i + 1
    End If
    Loop ' missing this


End Sub
```

Comment: This will still copy to SheetJ, not the new sheet??

Comment: I guess it would based on this line "Sheets("Sheetj").Select". If you need this code you can always customize to your needs. My goal was to assist with the OP's compilation errors. I am confident he could customize for his own uses from there.

Comment: Feel free to reply to the question with what you think is the correct answer. This is an open community ;)

Comment: yes a manior problem now after 6 hours of work `Sheets("Sheetj").Select` does need to become `Sheets("Sheets" & j).Select` to go to the sheet based on the integral of j

Comment: Lol got downvoted despite assisting the OP and resolving his problem.....care to comment why I deserve a down vote?

Comment: Is this at me? You need 125 Rep to down vote, I just earned the up vot that you just got!

Comment: No it was not at you you don't have enough reps to down vote, it was aimed to whoever down voted....

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
Loop
```

Before you end the sub. The i's also shouldn't have double quote if you're referencing what the number I should be. Should be like Cells(i , 1), or Cells(i , i), I'll leave you up to fix the rest.

Sorry, misread your original post. fixed.

Comment: one more issue- `Cells("A1")` is not correct syntax, `Range("A1")` is correct one.

Comment: Updated it to the way cells would use it. I keep blanking out haha. Long day at work.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this to add create new sheets for each data group.

*Updated: reduced my code now your "sheetj" part is clear*

*code*

```
Sub Other()   
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set rng1 = Sheets("Inventory").Range("I2:i6")
Set ws = Sheets.Add
For Each rng2 In rng1
    If rng2 <> rng2.Offset(-1, 0) Then Set ws = Sheets.Add
    rng2.EntireRow.Copy ws.Rows(rng2.Row)
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: @SeekingAlpha down-voting should be reserved for issues with the code. Feel free to point out the error if you see one.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but i think you use too many selects (tried with .activate ?)

```
Dim i As long 'long is faster for loops
Dim j As long

i = 2 'dont need set 
j = 1
Do While i < 6
    with Sheets("Inventory")
       If .Cells(i,1).Value = .Cells(i-1,1).Value Then  'i removed the quotes in cells
           .range("i:i").Copy Sheets("Sheetj").Cells(i,1)
           i = i + 1
       Else
           Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
           j = j + 1
           .Cells("i:i").copy Sheets("Sheetj").Range("A3")
           i = i + 1
       End If
    end with
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
loop  'you forgot a ending loop
```